# Convert rows to column postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, rows, crosstab

I got the following table

```
SHOPPER_TYPE | total_online_shopper | total_online_spent | total_online_visits | total_online_units | total_online_discout
-------------+----------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------
CM           |                   11 |                 22 |                  44 |                 55 |                  443
NM           |                   66 |                667 |                  22 |                 33 |                  448
```

I want to get the following result

```
Measures               |  CM |  NM
-----------------------+-----+----
total_online_shopper   |  11 |  66
total_online_spent     |  22 | 667
total_online_visits    |  44 |  22
total_online_units     |  55 |  33
total_online_discout   | 443 | 448
```

As I mention in the title I use PostgrSQL on pgadmin 9.3
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: The format of your data doesn't make sense.  It is unclear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Google pivot. Or it might be called cross tab in pgsql

Comment: @LJ01 I tried to figure it out with crosstab but it didn't work. If you can elaborate a bit more it will be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a lateral join and then aggregation:

```
select v.measure,
       max(case when t.SHOPPER_TYPE = 'CM' then v.val end) as cm,
       max(case when t.SHOPPER_TYPE = 'NM' then v.val end) as nm
from t, lateral
     (values ('total_online_shopper',  t.total_online_shopper), 
             ('total_online_spent', t.total_online_spent),
             ('total_online_visits', t.total_online_visits),
             ('total_online_units', t.total_online_units),
             ('total_online_discount', t.total_online_discount)
     ) v(measure, val)
group by v.measure;
```